# Downgrade Debian kernel

Tags: debian, kernel

I have a requirement to install Debian kernel 3.2.65-1+deb7u2.  I cannot seem to find the kernel.  I have taken the following steps:

1. Installed kernel 3.2.68-1+deb7u1.
2. Downgraded the kernel to 3.2.65-1. That is the only kernel available.
3. Performed an apt-get update, which gives the option of 3.2.68-1+deb7u1, which returns me my initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the relevant packages (which depend on your exact requirements) from [Debian snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux/3.2.65-1%2Bdeb7u2/).